# Glass Mapper support Experience Editor for child items

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I have  View rendering control for Sitecore 8 MVC,
This view render control render some children items for selected data source.

```
  public interface IBase
    {
        [SitecoreId]
        Guid Id { get; set; }
}
 public interface IRootCollection : IBase
    {
        [SitecoreChildren]
        IEnumerable<ICModel> Children { get; set; }
    }

   [SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{someid}", AutoMap = true)]
    public interface ICModel : IBase
    {

        Image Image { get; set; }

        string Title { get; set; }

        string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

I have next view render

```
@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<IRootCollection>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Children)
    {        
            <div class="col-lg-3">              
    @RenderImage(item , m => m.Image,  isEditable: true)
                    <h2>@Editable(item, m => m.Title)</h2>
                </a>
                <div>@Editable(item, m => m.Description)</div>
            </div>
                        }
                    }
```

Extra I have setup  Experience Editor Buttons for view render control. 
I can add,sort new ICModel item via Experience Editor, but I can't remove it.I can remove only full set of children items.
How to set up glass mapper for generate full support for Experience Editor.

Comment: You'll need to add a "delete" button and handle it, but your model needs the `[SitecoreId]` attribute added in order to map to the item

Comment: I have it actually I just skip it in my example. I just added it. How I can add delete button for child items.

Comment: @Arbejdsglæde maybe an edit frame to wrap the child item  ?

Comment: @nsgocev yes, but edit frame required some property.. if I use just BeginEditFrame  it broke UI view and no component name

Comment: add path to your model([SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.FullPath)]) and try something like this: @foreach (var item in Model.Children)
            {
                using (BeginEditFrame(item.Path))
                { 
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    @RenderImage(item, m => m.Image, isEditable: true)
                    <h2>@Editable(item, m => m.Title)</h2>
                    </a>
                    <div>@Editable(item, m => m.Description)</div>
                </div>
                }
            
            }

Comment: yes I got it, but not remove button for frame area got name like Page Area and no remove botton

Comment: The begin edit frame also accepts a set of buttons. You might want to create custom expiriance editor delete button or use the existing one

Comment: @msgocev sorry for extra question, How I can do it? Where I can set up the list of buttons ? may be you have some link to examples

Comment: @Arbejdsglæde the question never got a notification sorry. http://davegoosem.net/web-development/sitecore/add-edit-reorder-delete-content-sitecore-page-editor/

https://techmusingz.wordpress.com/2015/06/07/editframe-with-sitecore-mvc-and-glass-mapper/